# Running Python With Ajax Issues

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, electron

I want to run a Python script upon a 'click' event of a  Button in an Electron app I am building.

I have included the following code in the `mainWindow.html` page I am building to accomplish this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
// Run Upload
function runUpload(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "script_1_upload_to_drive.py",
        context: document.body
    }).done(function() {
        alert('Finished Python Script');;
    });
};
</script>
```

The error I am getting is the following:

> `TypeError: $.ajax is not a function`

I have done some looking around and it seems the common area is people accidentally using the slim version of JQuery. I have tried the following versions and nothing has changed the error:
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js

Comment: Open your browser console.  Looks like the `integrity` hash you are using is incorrect.

Comment: Download the jquery library, and use it

Comment: @Taplar you are right, the error I am getting is the following: Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'VAvG3sHdS5LqTT+5A/aeq/bZGa/Uj04xKxY8KM/w9EE='. The resource has been blocked. Is there a way to remedy this?

Comment: Download the version you want to use and serve it from your server, or use a version without the integrity hash, or find one with the correct hash.  I would also suggest choosing a different file from http://code.jquery.com/jquery/ anyway, as that "latest" is pointing to 1.11.x, which is **not** the latest (1.12.4 is the latest 1X version)

Comment: @Taplar so I used npm to download into my node_modules folder. Then I found the readme in the respective jquery folder and used the Script tag in there. It is the following: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>. Still getting the same error though.

Comment: Hold on, what exactly did you download from npm?

Comment: @Taplar wait do I need jsdom since I used npm?

Comment: npm install jquery

Comment: If you're downloading jQuery from npm, why do you need to reference the one from code.jquery.com?  You already downloaded it...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198735/discussion-between-emmett-ogiony-and-taplar).

Comment: I'm not experienced with using jQuery from npm, but this definitely sounds wrong.  If you download jQuery with npm, you have a version of it locally.  You do not need to reference a CDN version

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-BJeo0qm959uMBGb65z40ejJYGSgR7REI4+CW1fNKwOg=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-F0O1TmEa4I8N24nY0bya59eP6svWcshqX1uzwaWC4F4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

And use event listener to be sure the document is loaded :

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
   // The document load is finished, $ should be defined
   // Do what you want here
});
```

Comment: Not sure why but if I use the first script you posted and the 3.4.1 that Google hosts it works. But if I use one or the other it does not work. So confusing.

Comment: I don't know too,I think they are corrupted or something like that. It's the solution (version) I have found after many search. For event listener, sometime you don't need this, sometime another script like browser extensions for example "block" the loading and your script is fired before jquery initialization.